15-game graph contains a Hamiltonian path ? Lovász conjecture for groupoids, loops, quasigroups , etc?
Typically Cayley graphs are defined for groups and generators sets S. But basically one only needs some set S and another set V and partially defined operation SxV->V, then one defines graph with vertices V and one have an edge between $v_1,v_2$ if there exists $s \in S: v_1=sv_2$. So for definition nothing is required - neither associativity, neither identity and so definition works various types of algebraic structures: groupoids, monoids, quasigroups, etc...
The famous Lovász conjecture predicts existence of the Hamiltonian path for Cayley graphs of arbitrary finite groups.
Question 1: Are there any results or expectations when we somehow relax group condition to groupoid, loop, semigroup, or whatever...
Question 2: In particular graphs of states/transitions for  famous 15-game or its NxN analogs, or other sliding puzzles or  M13 Mathieu groupoid by Conway - are they expected to contain a Hamiltonian path ?
Question 3: One can also take Octonions, Sedenions,  Pathions, Chingons (etc. by Cayley–Dickson construction ) take their units and construct "Cayley" graphs from these units -  same question .
All graphs are considered undirected. (Any information for directed graphs is also welcome, but it is already known for groups that directed Hamiltonian paths not always exists).

The graph might not be connected.  For instance take a right zero semigroup with two or more elements and you get either an edge free graph or loops at the vertices

In any event it is not natural to use unidirected graphs with no inverses.

Yes, sure we can have many connected components, so we can for each of them or for some.

Well it depends , e.g. you can embed in object with  inverses . If not does  it imply - no Hamiltonian path ? So there is kind of degrees of freedom...
